# Menu in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to Make Calculator NavBar Menus and to link them to various Components

Like

Home
Addition
Subtraction

How do I achieve in React.JS

I have added Components in Apps.js for Navbar
but could not figure out other components to link

Please advice
Regards

Comment: i think you're looking for a drop-down menu https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should put your own research efforts into solving your problem, show what you have tried, and add a brief description of your efforts plus the actual code that you have written plus the precise problem that you're facing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this type of menu by making a custom component with the name `DropDownMenu` or whatever you like to name it. let's have look at this pseudo code example.

```
 // array = [ {text : 'add' , onClick = () => {} } ]
 function DropDownMenu (props) { 
  return ( <>{props.array && props.array.map((child , idx) => 
             <DropDownChild text = {child.text} onClick = {child.onClick} 
          /> ) </> 
       )
 }

function DropDownChild (props) {
   return ( <><a onClick = {props.onClick} >{props.text}</a> )
}
```

> Don't Forget to add styling https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Demo https://codepen.io/mustafa-turk/pen/ExYzvmr